# How to code my own dot product using a Python class?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, class, numpy-ndarray

I want to create a subclass of `numpy` adding a new method. Here is my first step:

```
class MyNumpy(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self):
        np.ndarray.__init__(self)
    
    def my_inner(self, x, y):
        dotpr = 2*x[0]*y[0] + 3*x[1]*y[1]
        return dotpr
```

Obviously `my_inner()` is wrong, but I wrote it here to show what I want.
Commenting out `my_inner()`, and typing in

```
p = MyNumpy([0.1, 0.2])
print("type(p): ", type(p))
p
```

the error message is produced

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-2cee31ae802a> in <module>
 ----> 1 p = MyNumpy([0.1, 0.2])
  2 print("type(p): ", type(p))
  3 p

TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I don't know what this `'float'` object refers to here. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: `np.ndarray` intialization takes the first argument as `shape`. In this case, it interprete `[0.1,0.2]` as the shape of the data. Maybe, you should use `np.array` instead of `np.ndarray`.

Comment: Omit the `__init__` if all you are doing is adding some methods.  Otherwise, subclassing ndarray is not a good starting point. There are complications you don't need to deal  with now.

Answer (score 1):

As @Quang Hoang pointed out, when you initiate the `np.ndarray` you pass it a shape, and it should be of type `int`, like:

```
class MyNumpy(np.ndarray):
    def __init__(self, shape):
        super().__init__()
    
    def my_inner(self, x, y):
        dotpr = 2*x[0]*y[0] + 3*x[1]*y[1]
        return dotpr

p = MyNumpy((2, 6))
print("type(p): ", type(p))
p
```

cheers.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In the meantime I found a solution which uses decorators, and for some reasons I prefer it. (I use it in a more complicated situation.)